# Postgresql invalid salt

Tags: postgresql, pgcrypto

I have a table with about 6,000 records. Each record includes a column named user_name whose value is a crypt generated hash.

When I run this sql:

```
select entity_id from mytable where user_name = crypt('tdriver', user_name) and last_name = 'Test';
```

I get this result:
entity_id = 33, which is correct.

When I run this sql:

```
select entity_id from mytable where user_name = crypt('tdriver', user_name);
```

I get this result

`ERROR:  invalid salt`

I am using Postgresql 13. My guess is that Postgresql is corrupted and I will need to reinstall it.

Comment: My guess is that the second statement finds a row that causes the error. Figure out which row that is, and what the value of `user_name` is in that row.

Comment: Thank you for the edits and suggestion. The issue was that not all records have a value for user_name.